# Problems on SQL Server Express remote connection

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server Express remote database, in a domained network. The server is running in 50833 port, wich I've openned in firewall. Testing with `telnet xx.xxx.xxx.xx 50833`, connection is ok. When I try to configure ODBC DataSources to connect the Server, I receive a connection error like "Connection failed SQL Estate '08001' SQL Server Error -1: Error locating Server/Instance Specified." What should be going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What does your ODBC connection look like?  Is there an instance name on the DB?

Comment: Is SSE configured for TCP connections? Check SQL Server Configuration Manager under the "Network Configuration" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you may not be specifying the port number properly in your ODBC config.
Please consult the "client setup" part of [this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195566) to make sure that your ODBC connection specifies the port number (i.e. instance name) properly.